# ShouldReceiveTouch for continuous gestures

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer, uibezierpath

I have a UIBezierPath for which I want to perform hit tests with the containsPoint method. By using UIGestureRecognizerDelegate method shouldReceiveTouch I'm in this way able to detect touches on the actual bezierpath and allowing touches outside the path to be passed up the responder chain (which is the desired behavior).

This works perfectly fine with taps, but the problem arises when it comes to continuous gestures, i.e. panning, because shouldReceiveTouch doesn't cover the touchesMoved event.

I can use the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate method gestureRecognizerShouldBegin to block the entire continuous gesture but then the gesture isn't passed on to the next responder.

Is subclassing UIGestureRecognizer and get touchesMoved to call shouldReceiveTouch the way to go about it? Or could I achieve this by clipping the path, does this also result in passing on the events outside the clipped area?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up overriding pointInside:withEvent in my UIView subclass that draws the bezier path. This way I'm able to handle both discrete and continuous gestures and forward the event to the superview.